# ExtJS grid problem with html

Tags: javascript, html, json, extjs, grid

I have an ExtJS grid connected to a store. When I add a thumbnail column with an `<img>` tag inside store, grid shows `0`. Is there some kind of html filtering? If I change the store data to something without html tags it shows fine. Excuse my awful English and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

some time ago we put img in cell like this:

Column model:

```
{ header: "", dataIndex:'thumb', width:0.1, renderer:this.makeImg.createDelegate(this) }
```

Where this.makeImg():

```
makeImg:function(val, cell, record){
    var data = record.data;
    return '<img src="'+val+'" title="'+data.name+'" width="75" />';

},
```

Comment: BTW - You could add "scope: this" instead of creating a delegate for the renderer

Comment: ob1, yeap, you are right. Setting scope is better in this situation.